# htaccess and CakePHP3 routing (multiple "sites" same server)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

Okay so I need just a little bit of help, I think i almost have my routing clean but am running into one small issue.

I am trying to setup one server to handle multiple different static sites as well as a cakephp 3 installation.

The root .htaccess has the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%2/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%2,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```

This works great for routing subdomains to their proper folder

static.domain.com properly goes to /static/index.php

the problem comes when i try to access my cake installation

cake.domain.com ends up routing to cake.domain.com/cake/$1

I really need it to route to cake.domain.com/$1

/cake/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /cake
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/cake/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /cake
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I will be eternally grateful for any help, i have exhausted google searching and banging my head on the wall.

I am completely open to easier ideas as well

Comment: Try with `RewriteBase /cake/` 2x with 2x `/`

Comment: i had tried that, no go.  it is still addinging /cake to the end

Comment: Solved.  In the app.php i changed the base from false to "" (empty).  It was automagically finding the base as /cake/ when it needed to just be / because my root htaccess rewrote it properly.